# MySQL Query Distinct ID over multiple lines

Tags: mysql

MySQL table 'Features'

```
prop_id    name
----------------------------
1          Wifi
2          Off Road Parking
1          Off Road Parking
2          Close to beach
3          Close to Pub
1          Close to Pub
```

Prop_id is the id in another table of the property

what i would like to do is get the id's of all the properties where they have 'Wifi' and 'Close to pub'

so in this case i would like it to only return 1

Hope that i have made sence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, one ugly way is:

```
select prop_id from features
   where name = 'Wifi' and prop_id in (
       select prop_id from features where name = 'Close to Pub'
       )
```

Comment: Spot on mate! cheers for that!! i have been racking my brains for ages about this.

Comment: You can also read up on JOINs for other solutions and similar stuff. I really like the "Wifi" and "Close to Pub" entries in your database. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT prop_id FROM table WHERE name="Wifi" or name="Close to pub"
```

Comment: this would give me ids for ones that just have wifi and not wifi and close to pub